# Python Matplotlib Combine legend from histogram and lines

Tags: python, legend, matplotlib, histogram, scatterplot

I wrote a **Python** script that uses **matplotlib twinx** to combine a histogram and some line functions plot as can see in the figure. However I was not capable of combining both legends (nb of points and lines).

How can I do that?
I tryed **get_legend_handles_labels()** and **fig.legend()** with no success.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy


numpy.random.seed(19680801)

# example data
mu = 5000  # mean of distribution
sigma = 1500  # standard deviation of distribution
r1 = mu + sigma * numpy.random.randn(437)
sug_spec = numpy.arange(0, 10001, 100)
accuracy = sug_spec/2
precision = sug_spec/3
uncertainty = sug_spec/4

num_bins = 100
bins = numpy.arange(0, 10100, num_bins)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlabel('Surface Reflectance Truth')

# Plot lines
color = 'tab:pink'
ax.plot(bins, sug_spec, color=color)
color = 'tab:red'
ax.plot(bins, accuracy, color=color)
color = 'tab:green'
ax.plot(bins, precision, color=color)
color = 'tab:blue'
ax.plot(bins, uncertainty, color=color)

# Instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax2 = ax.twinx()

# Order of each plot (Front, Back)
ax.set_zorder(2)
ax2.set_zorder(1)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)

# Remove scientific notation
ax2.ticklabel_format(style='plain')

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(r1, num_bins, edgecolor="k")

ax.legend(['suggested specs','accuracy','precision','uncertainty'], frameon=False, loc=1)
ax2.legend(['nb of points'], frameon=False, loc=5)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to [manually add a legend entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500265/manually-add-legend-items-python-matplotlib):

```
# where some data has already been plotted to ax
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# manually define a new patch 
patch = mpatches.Patch(color='grey', label='Manual Label')

# handles is a list, so append manual patch
handles.append(patch) 

# plot the legend
plt.legend(handles=handles, loc='upper center')
```

So in your case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Nov 20 10:07:19 2020

@author: joempie
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy


numpy.random.seed(19680801)

# example data
mu = 5000  # mean of distribution
sigma = 1500  # standard deviation of distribution
r1 = mu + sigma * numpy.random.randn(437)
sug_spec = numpy.arange(0, 10001, 100)
accuracy = sug_spec/2
precision = sug_spec/3
uncertainty = sug_spec/4

num_bins = 100
bins = numpy.arange(0, 10100, num_bins)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlabel('Surface Reflectance Truth')

# Plot lines
color = 'tab:pink'
ax.plot(bins, sug_spec, color=color,label='suggested specs')
color = 'tab:red'
ax.plot(bins, accuracy, color=color,label='accuracy')
color = 'tab:green'
ax.plot(bins, precision, color=color,label='precision')
color = 'tab:blue'
ax.plot(bins, uncertainty, color=color,label='uncertainty')



# Instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax2 = ax.twinx()

# Order of each plot (Front, Back)
ax.set_zorder(2)
ax2.set_zorder(1)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)

# Remove scientific notation
ax2.ticklabel_format(style='plain')

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(r1, num_bins, edgecolor="k", color="blue")

# where some data has already been plotted to ax
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# manually define a new patch 
rectangle = Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, color='blue',ec='k',label='nb of points') 
# handles is a list, so append manual patch
handles.append(rectangle) 

# plot the legend
plt.legend(handles=handles, loc='upper center')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the manually defined rectangle does not follow 'edgecolor="k"' style.

Comment: `edgecolor` defines the edge color of your histogram. In this case, you did not define a color for the bars. If you set `color='blue'` when plotting the histogram, it will match. I'm not sure what the default color is, you'd have to find that. (I've added `color='blue'` to the code)